# If function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is such that $\{x: f(x)>k\}$ and $\{x: f(x)<k\}$ are open for all real $k$, then $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Prove that if the function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$, such that for all $k$ from $\Bbb{R}$, the sets $\{x: f(x)>k\}$ and $\{x: f(x)<k\}$ are open, then $f$ is continuous.

So, if $\{x: f(x)>k\}$ and $\{x: f(x)<k\}$, that means that the two sets contain their limit point. Also, there are open ball, that are centered in point from the given sets, but contain both point that are in the sets and points that are not in the sets.

Where from here?

Any hint would be good. Thank you!

Comment: Any open set in $\mathbb R$ is a countable disjoint union of open intervals.

Comment: Open sets do not necessarily contain their limit points (rather that's the property of closed sets), but open sets have the property that each point of the set is an interior point ie each point is surrounded by a neighborhood wholly contained in the set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint**

Prove the continuity of $f$ for any $x \in [a,b]$.

For this take $\epsilon \gt 0$ and consider the  relations

$$\begin{aligned}f^{-1}[(f(x)-\epsilon,f(x)+ \epsilon)]&=f^{-1}[ (f(x)- \epsilon, \infty) \cap (-\infty, f(x)+\epsilon)]\\
&= f^{-1}[ (f(x)- \epsilon, \infty)]\cap f^{-1}[(-\infty, f(x)+\epsilon)]
\end{aligned}$$ which is open according to the hypothesis’s and to the fact that the intersection of two open subsets is open.